# Pdf to Text Converter in AIX

Tags: aix, pdf, conversion

I need to convert **PDF to Text files in AIX**. How can I do that?  I got the XPDF util for Linux and windows. But specifically looking for AIX server. Also any licensed version would work, we can buy.

Comment: A breadcrumb: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Power+Systems/page/How+to+install+a+PDF+viewer+on+AIX

Comment: Hi Jeff, I had tried this one too. They have many supporting file missing and not working the way, it is mentioned over there. No luck.

Answer (score 2):

The package **poppler-utils** contains the `pdftotext` command. It is available from e.g. http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Poppler